# How to choose location to save file excel with PHPExcel

Tags: php, yii, phpexcel

I have a problem when using PHPExcel to create a excel file. I want to choose location to save file excel but I don't know how do it.

```
 $model = new User();
 $labels = $model->attributeNames();
 $data = $model->findAll();
 $objPHPExcel = Yii::app()->excel;

........
$filename = 'text.xlsx';
$objWriter = new PHPExcel_Writer_Excel2007($objPHPExcel);
$objWriter->save($filename);
```

Please help me. thank you so much.

Comment: did you try changing `$filename` as `/path/to/save/text.xlsx` ?

Comment: You can't control where a user's/client's browser saves the file, not should you be able to.... consider if you tried to save to `/etc/passwd` on the users machine, that would be an incredible security flaw if it was permitted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you include below headers to your php file. Your users will have a download option pop-up:

```
header("Pragma: public");
header("Expires: 0");
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
header("Content-Type: application/force-download");
header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
header("Content-Type: application/download");;
header("Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=$filename");
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary ");
```

Answer (score 10):

Change the file name to desired path i.e,

```
$name = '/path/to/folder/xyz.xlsx';
$objWriter->save($name);
```

It Works For Me...

Answer (score 6):

```
$objWriter->save($filename);
```

.... change the value of `$filename` to be the filepath for wherever you want to save the file, e.g.

```
$filename = '/path/to/folder/test.xlsx';
$objWriter->save($filename);
```

Comment: example:  I have 1 button when click button show window to choose location save. how do it ?

Comment: You mean you want to send the file to the user's browser? And let them select what folder they want to save the file in on their PC?

Comment: Then send the appropriate headers, and save to `php://output` as shown in `/Examples/01simple-download-xlsx.php`

Comment: @MarkBaker What will be the headers? I am creating multiple files using while loop how can I save all files in a specific folder. Above code works fine but the file cannot open.

Comment: @ZaidBinKhalid If you want to save the files to disk, then you provide a filesystem filename to the `save()` method instead of the output stream... that saves to a file on the server which you can zip and then send the zipfile to the browser... but http limits you to one request, one response, you can't send more than one output/file back to the server at a time

Comment: @MarkBaker Thank you it is working fine for me. I just pass the absolute path and remove all headers.

Answer (score 0):

TO DOWNLOAD EXCEL WITH  PHPExcel:

```
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
```

For .xls files created with the Excel5 Writer:

```
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel'); //mime type
```

OR

For .xlsx files created with the Excel2007 Writer:

```
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet'); //mime type

header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="you-file-name.xlsx"'); //tell browser what's the file name
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0'); //no cache 
ob_end_clean();
$objWriter->save('php://output'`enter code here`);
exit();
```